# MySQL: Optimizing query for calculation of financial BETA

Tags: mysql, optimization

in finance, a stock's beta is the covariance between the stock's daily returns and an index' daily returns divided by the variance of the index daily returns. I try to calaculate beta for set of stocks and a set of indices.

Here's my query for a 50 business day rolling window and I'd like you to help me optimize it for speed:

```
INSERT INTO betas (permno, index_id, DATE, beta) 
(SELECT 
  permno, index_id, s.date, IF(
    s.`seq` >= 50, 
    (SELECT 
 (AVG(s2.log_return*i2.log_return)-AVG(s2.log_return)*AVG(i2.log_return))/VAR_POP(i2.log_return) AS beta
    FROM
      stock_series s2
      INNER JOIN `index_series` i2 ON i2.date=s2.date 
      WHERE i2.index_id=i.index_id AND s2.permno = s.permno 
      AND s2.`seq` BETWEEN s.`seq` - 49 AND s.`seq` 
      GROUP BY index_id,permno), NULL)
   AS beta 
FROM
  stock_series s
  INNER JOIN `index_series` i ON i.index_id IN ('SP500') AND i.date=s.date
 ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE beta=  VALUES (beta)
```

Both main tables are already ordered by entity and date in ascending order, and they already include log daily returns as well as a "seq" column. Seq sequentally enumerates all daily rows company- (or index-) wise, i.e. seq starts over at 1 for every new stock or index in the table and counts up to the number of total number of rows for a given entity. I created it to allow for the rolling window.

As of now, with 500 firms and 1 index, the query takes like forever to complete.
Let me know any optimization that comes to your mind, like views, stored procs, temp tables, and if you find any inconsistencies, of course.

EDIT: Indexes:
stock_series has PRIMARY KEY (permno,date) and UNIQUE KEY (permno,seq),
index_series has PRIMARY KEY (index_id,date)

EXPLAIN EXTENDED results for ONE company (by including a WHERE s.permno=... restriction at the end):
[image: EXPLAIN EXTENDED of above SELECT query]

EXPLAIN EXTENDED results for ALL ~500 companies:
[image]

Comment: Do you have an index on 'seq' column? What all indexes are present for this table.

Comment: just posted the indexes in the main post

Comment: Try creating an index on date, index_id, permno and seq. From the data it looks like it is "End Of Day" data, is that the case?. If this index does not help, DO post Execution plan of this query. We can identify bottleneck from the plan.

Comment: it is end of day data! i can try your index and then report what it did. what do you mean exactly by execution plan?

Comment: Run the query with "EXPLAIN". This would show steps MySQL would take to execute the query. Example : http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/24/extended-explain/   This might highlight the bottleneck.

Comment: as for the the index, i'm not sure how you mean it: all these columns are NOT in the same table currently

Comment: @shamit: i just added the explain extended results for you above. at least, every subquery seems to use a key. do you see potential for optimization?

Answer (score -1):

Here i what the pros do: do NOT calcualte that in the databae. Pull data, calculate, reinsert. Where I work now they have a hugh grid doing that stuff in the end of day run. Yes, gris - like in a significant number of machines. We talk of producing gigabytes of csv files that then get reloaded into the database. Beta, Gamma, PnL on trades with 120.000 different elements. Databaes are NOT optimized for this.

Comment: i do know that, and i also know how to do it myself in Excel VBA or whatever language. The thing is that such a solution presents a lot of work and I won't need to run my beta calculations very often. That's why I'd like to try to keep it in pure MySQL. Could also be a stored procedure iterating over every row.